# How to 'destroy/dispose' frame% in plt-scheme?

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket

I want to destory my previously shown frame when a certain event is triggered.
I can't find anything regarding this in the reference manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to -- just `(send frame show #f)` to hide it.  When the value is no longer reachable, it will be garbage-collected.